# $\arctan(x)\frac{x^2}{2}$ vs $(\arctan(x))\frac{x^2}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, notation

While I was doing a math on paper today, I wrote

$$\arctan x\ \frac{x^2}{2}$$

As the expression is ambiguous, I tried to make it less so by writing

$$\arctan(x)\frac{x^2}{2}\tag{1}$$

Is $(1)$ clear enough or should I write the following:

$$(\arctan(x))\frac{x^2}{2}\tag{2}$$

$(2)$ seems redundant in my opinion.

Comment: I like Misha's approach if you are set on avoiding parentheses entirely.  If you want to be clear but sparing of parentheses and keeping your expression in the same "order", then $(\arctan x)\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expression $(1)$ is clear enough in my opinion, in the sense that you can read it as "everything I use as an input is between the parentheses."

Expression $(2)$, while cumbersome, is completely unambiguous. There is a degree of redundancy there, but making things unambiguous tends to make the notation more cumbersome -- it's a tradeoff.

However, I second Misha's suggestion of writing

$$\frac{x^2}{2} \arctan(x)$$

Usually whenever I have a function like that in a term -- be it $f(x)$, $\sin(x)$, $\exp(x)$, $\zeta(x)$, who knows -- it feels more natural to put everything that is *not* like that to the left of the function. That way there is no still ambiguity as to what is and isn't an argument of the function.

Answer (score 8):

Why not write $\frac{x^2}{2} \arctan x$? Something like $\arctan(x)\frac{x^2}{2}$ seems clear to me, but still slightly unusual, and usually people put trig-style functions at the end of every term, just to avoid this sort of problem.