# Should I be worried about putting brackets around derivatives when I'm using chain rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, chain-rule, convention

$$\frac{d}{d(2\cot\theta)}(\tan^{-1}2\cot\theta)\cdot\frac{d}{d(\cot\theta)}(2\cot\theta)\cdot\frac{d}{d\theta}(\cot\theta)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\theta\tag{1}$$

$$\left(\frac{d}{d(2\cot\theta)}(\tan^{-1}2\cot\theta)\right)\cdot\left(\frac{d}{d(\cot\theta)}(2\cot\theta)\right)\cdot\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}(\cot\theta)\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\theta\tag{2}$$

$$4\sin2x\cos2x\tag{3}$$

$$4(\sin2x)(\cos2x)\tag{4}$$

$(2)$ is completely unambiguous. No one can misinterpret anything. However, in $(1)$, one can misinterpret, for example, $\frac{d}{d(2\cot\theta)}(\tan^{-1}2\cot\theta)\cdot\frac{d}{d(\cot\theta)}(2\cot\theta)$ as meaning $\frac{d}{d(2\cot\theta)}\left[(\tan^{-1}2\cot\theta)\cdot\frac{d}{d(\cot\theta)}(2\cot\theta)\right]$ instead of $\left(\frac{d}{d(2\cot\theta)}(\tan^{-1}2\cot\theta)\right)\cdot\left(\frac{d}{d(\cot\theta)}(2\cot\theta)\right)$.

Similarly, $(4)$ is completely unambiguous. No one can misinterpret anything. However, in $(3)$, one can misinterpret $\sin2x\cos2x$ as meaning $\sin(2x\cos2x)$ instead of $(\sin2x)(\cos2x)$.

Is this a minor thing? Should I be worried about putting brackets obsessively? I experience so much anxiety now while doing math.

---

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4379323/768162)

Comment: Clarity > brevity. In fact, brevity often results in ambiguity, which wastes more time than putting a few more symbols (or words) which would makes everything unambiguous. So I prefer $(2)$ and $(4)$ over $(1)$ and $(3).$

Comment: Are expressions (1) and (2) really (commonly) a thing?

Comment: @ryang I didn't see $(2)$ written anywhere. My book uses a different version of $(1)$, though:

$$\frac{d(\tan^{-1}2\cot\theta)}{d(2\cot\theta)}\cdot\frac{d(2\cot\theta)}{d(\cot\theta)}\cdot\frac{d(\cot\theta)}{d\theta}\cdot\frac{d\theta}{dx}\tag{*}$$

Comment: @ryang Now that I think about it, is $(*)$ the exact same as writing $(1)$?

Comment: 1. To me, (\*) and (2) are essentially identical, while (1) *pretty much* (due to the product dots)  means the same, my dislike of their common notation (hinted in my previous comment) notwithstanding; the only ambiguity (contrary to your assertion that (2) is unambiguous) is what the argument of that arctan is. $\quad$ 2. Similarly (and pedantically), (4) isn't completely unambiguous either: after all, $\sin 2x$ is interpretable as $(\sin 2)x.$ $\quad$ 3. Related: [powers in trig functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4058720/21813)

Comment: @ryang You're right. arctan is still ambiguous in (2), and (4) is also ambiguous still. Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as spaces are important in separating words, so they are in mathematical notation. Thus $\sin2x$ means $\sin(2x)$, and $\sin2x\cos2x$ means $(\sin2x)(\cos2x)$. If we really mean $\sin(2x\cos2x)$, then we have to add the parentheses to override the spacing convention. To override the usual convention that multiplication (denoted by juxtaposition) operates before other operations, we can use a centered dot. Thus $\sin2\cdot x$ means $(\sin2)x$ rather than $\sin2x$.

The spacing convention implies that the notation $\tan^{-1}2\cot\theta$ means $(\tan^{-1}2)\cot\theta$. If we intend $\tan^{-1}(2\cot\theta)$, then the parentheses are necessary.

The dots in your expression #1 make it unambiguous, and there is no need to add the (big) parentheses as in expression #2. Also, the parentheses in $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}(\cot\theta)$ are redundant, but they are not redundant in $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}(2\cot\theta)$. Thus $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\cot\theta=-\csc^2\theta$, while $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}2\cot\theta=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}2\cdot\cot\theta=0$.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what the spacing convention **is**. In $\sin 2x$, we interpreted it as $\sin(2x)$, probably because there is a single space between $\sin$ and $2x$, and there is no space between $2$ and $x$ in $2x$. In $\tan^{-1}2\cot\theta$, there is a single space between $\tan^{-1}$ and $2\cot\theta$, and there is no space between $2$ and $\cot\theta$ in $2\cot\theta$, just like in the case of $\sin 2x$; why is it then interpret-able as $(\tan^{-1}2)\cot\theta$ instead of $\tan^{-1}(2\cot\theta)$ according to the spacing convention?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic 1. Mathematical writing, very much like natural language, is not a formal language, and conventions (spacing, product/centred dots, etc.) are not rigorous systems, but can be combined and meant to complement judgement and *unspoken* conventions (and the surrounding context). I'm confident that you can typically detect expressions that are actually ambiguous (rather than merely technically ambiguous like my above contrived $(\sin2)x$ example). That $(\sin2)x$ ambiguity was tricky to detect precisely because *nobody* would read it that way.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic 2. "In $\tan^{-1}2\cot\theta,$ there is a single space between $\tan^{-1}$ and $2\cot\theta,$ and there is no space between $2$ and $\cotθ$ in $2\cotθ$" $\;$ But there ***is*** a (thin) space between $2$ and $\cotθ;$ it is automatically inserted by mathjax, and is why `$\sin\theta\tan(x)$` and `$\sin \theta \tan (x)$` have exactly the same output.